# Connecting from windows to debian Samba share

Tags: samba, zfs, windows-10, proxmox

I have a proxmox installation with a few ZFS shares.
The shares are created using

```bash
zfs create storage/photos
sudo zfs set acltype=posixacl storage/photos
```

The user is created using

```bash
sudo adduser --system --no-create-home samba-peter
sudo smbpasswd -a samba-peter
sudo setfacl -R -m "u:samba-peter:rwx" /storage/photos
```

then I add

```ini
[photos]
   comment = photos
   path = /storage/photos
   read only = no
   writable = yes
   browseable = yes
   guest ok = no
   valid users = @samba-peter
```

to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and increase logging using `log level = 2 winbind:5`.

Now when I try to connect using `Windows 10 21H2 19044.2604` it logs

```
==> /var/log/samba/log.smbd <==
[2023/03/06 17:22:10.679844,  2] ../../source3/lib/tallocmsg.c:84(register_msg_pool_usage)
  Registered MSG_REQ_POOL_USAGE

==> /var/log/samba/log.192.168.0.19 <==
[2023/03/06 17:22:10.685627,  2] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:323(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [samba-peter] -> [samba-peter] -> [samba-peter] succeeded
[2023/03/06 17:22:10.686016,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2864(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[photos]"

==> /var/log/samba/log.fryr <==
[2023/03/06 17:22:10.689318,  1] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:362(create_connection_session_info)
  create_connection_session_info: user 'samba-peter' (from session setup) not permitted to access this share (photos)
[2023/03/06 17:22:10.689346,  1] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:543(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

It seems that the authentication succeeds (if I login using the wrong password the log states that the password was incorrect).
But access to the directory fails, but what am I missing I gave it access using `setfacl -R -m "u:samba-peter:rwx" /storage/photos`

Samba version: Version 4.13.13-Debian
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Kernel: Linux 5.15.85-1-pve
ZFS Version: zfs-2.1.9-pve1, zfs-kmod-2.1.9-pve1

Comment: I even tried to set samba-peter as owner of `/storage/photos` using `sudo chown -R samba-peter /storage/photos` sadly that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valid users = @samba-peter` specifies that users belonging to the `group samba-peter` are allowed.
Either drop the `@` or make sure that peter belongs to the group `samba-peter`

Comment: You are setting the permissions with setfacl, are you using 'vfs objects = acl_xattr' in the '[global]' part of your smb.conf ?

Comment: Thanks i will give it a try ( i know for a fact that the user has no group)

Comment: @Tschösi thanks that did it!!!